Which of these is the right way to interpret finding the current across a coil
If we have a coil which has a resistance of 100 ohms an induced emf of say 20V and this is connected to an AC power source of 100V and is in a series connection with another resistor of lets say 50 ohms then I have a question about how we should find the current through the coil.
so first of all we know that the voltage across the coil is now 80V because the back emf opposes the voltage due to the power source.
Does the current then equal to
$I=80/100$
I was thinking this because of Kirchoff Second circuit law
or does it equal
$I=80/150$
I was thinking this because Id take the total voltage and the total resitance to find the total current as the total current is in series and so will experience the same current as the total current.

This question is different from the one you have provided a link for. If the induced emf is the result of the self inductance of the coil then treating it as an ac problem the induced emf will not be in phase with the current and the supply voltage.

Model the coil as an ideal inductor in series with its 100 ohm resistance. That, in turn, is in series with the 50 ohm resistor. The voltage across the inductor is across the combination of the ideal coil and its resistance.
Hope this helps.

I'm not that familiar with inductors really . Can you tell me which of my interpretations is the correct one so I can use your answer as reference

I thought it was 150 ohms originally because I thought to treat it as the total resistance of the whole circuit to find I total but someone told me I was wrong and should take it as 100

if possible can you explain at highschool level

@hoff You can't do either because the current equals the voltage divided by the impedance. The impedance is the sum of the inductive reactance and the total resistance, a complex number.

This came up as highschool question I was trying to study from a past paper. Was the advice I got here incorrect ? https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/810194/why-is-the-voltage-across-the-coil-the-difference-between-the-induced-emf-and-th?noredirect=1#comment1820757_810194

also they dont teach impedance at all in highschool so are you saying this question is actually impossible

@hoff You can't calculate the current without understanding impedance. To calculate the impedance you need to know the frequency of the 120 vac source and you need to know the inductance $L$ of the coil in Henrys. Then you need to know that  inductive reactance of the coil is $j2\pi fL$ where $j$ is the imaginary number $\sqrt {-1}$. I don't know if they have given you any of this in HS.

they haven't no. I kinda understand it from reading articles but not enough to be confident and it's definitely not what they want in any exam. So basically the question is impossible with the information given and the person who answered my question in that link was wrong then yes ?

@hoff If the question is what is the current, then the information given is insufficient.
